# Bar Chart.js doesn't show values with PHP, MySQL, AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm using Chart.js plugin to create a bar chart with sales and purchases values by year. These values are stores in mysql database and I bring it via PHP/AJAX.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="mybarChart"></canvas>
```

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT YEAR(date) as years, SUM(amount) AS total FROM purchases GROUP BY YEAR(date)";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$totalpurchases = [];

$sqll = "SELECT YEAR(date) as years, SUM(amount) AS total FROM sales GROUP BY YEAR(date)";
$ress = mysql_query($sqll);
$totalsales = [];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $totalpurchases[] = [$row['total']];
}

while($roww = mysql_fetch_array($ress)){
    $totalsales[] = [$roww['total']];
}

echo json_encode(array($totalpurchases,$totalsales));
```

And I made my **JS** code like this:

```
function show_chartbar(lbl01,lbl02){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart");
    var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"],
            datasets: [{
            label: '# Total Purchase',
            backgroundColor: "#26B99A",
            data: lbl01
            }, {
            label: '# Total Sales',
            backgroundColor: "#03586A",
            data: lbl02
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
               yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                     }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}

if ($('#mybarChart').length ){    

    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/values.php",
        type: "GET",                    
        dataType: "json",               
        success: function(resp)
        {
            var totpurchases = resp[0];
            var totsales = resp[1];
            console.log("Total Purchases: "+totpurchases);
            console.log("Total Sales: "+totsales);
            show_chartbar(totpurchases,totsales);
        }
    });

}
```

In console it's showing values correctly but it doesn't display in the chart:

[image]

I tried to add additional brackets in data option but it's showing the same.

**UPDATE**

```
console.dir(resp);
```

[image]

How can I fix it? I'd like some help.

Comment: I would imagine your data is looking for an array, and your getting back an object from the json_encode since arrays work on Key value pairs. Can you `console.dir(resp)` in your ajax success function and show us the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an Array of Arrays. I believe this will fix this issue.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $totalpurchases[] = $row['total'];
}

while($roww = mysql_fetch_array($ress)){
    $totalsales[] = $roww['total'];
}
```